# Can a Windows update brick hardware across operating systems?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, mouse, touchpad

Ok this is going to be strange.

I have a Dell XPS 13 (9350 -- late 2015). Recently I installed Windows Insider Update 16226. As I have a dual boot set-up with Ubuntu Linux 16.04, one of Windows' reboots landed me in Linux and I had forgotten about the Windows set up when I came home later that night and closed my laptop lid.

When I next opend my computer, it had booted up my Linux environment and I decided to start working but the mouse pointer didn't react to any input on the trackpad.

I restarted into Windows, let it finish the setup and noticed that I could move the mouse, but all multitouch functionality had gone. The `i2c hid device` cannot be started, says device manager. Rebooting back into Linux, the synclient tells me there's no hardware installed. For a week I am unable to do any work but I still hope to rule out a hardware error.

Then Windows Insider Build 16232 comes along, and after installing it, the multitouch functionality is back in Windows, and strangely enough, the Linux pointer works as it used to.

**Question:** How is this possible? That a software update in an OS on one partition affects the software in the OS on another?! Did the Windows update secretly try to flash the trackpad firmware? I don't see how else it is possible. But surely, this is beyond the responsibilities of an OS update?

Comment: No;  A Windows Update cannot brick a x86 Intel/AMD machine

Comment: Yes, a Windows Update can brick a machine because it can alter BIOS-EFI related settings.

Comment: @Overmind, that is interesting. I did have a look through my UEFI settings and even reflashed the BIOS but I found nothing that could have disabled the trackpad's 'advanced' functionality.

Comment: Nothing else known so far could have cross-OS influence. Look specially into chipset/USB settings. Usually messing with the Advanced USB settings and not only affect a lot all HIDs.

Comment: The conditions to reproduce it have disappeared so no way for me to check what exactly had gone wrong. Afaik the settings in UEFI/BIOS were identical as before the installation but I may have missed something.

Comment: Technically any OS update, Windows or Linux, has the potential to brick your machine.  That's why you backup your machine. Any program with the correct system calls can modify the BIOS-EFI. It does take **admin permissions** however.